# Definite integration - how to find area under a curve?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

so I was doing my homework and go to the "complex unfamiliar" questions which arent required to be completed but I still want to understand and get an answer.

The question refers to a valuation of a torn banknote as in Australia if greater than 80% of the note is still there full face value is given, between 80 and 20% the percentage value of the note is given and below 20% no value is given.

I can do the translation of area to percent to get an answer, I just don't know how to get the area in the first place, and that's where I am stuck.

[this is the graph that I generated from the points below, I measured in 0.5cm increments and then measured the height which is the y, the polynomial regression is there solely for visual stimulus and comunication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSks0.png)

[These are the dimension (points/ measurements) of the banknote all of it is in cm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roIwE.png)

I know for a fact my calculations are incorrect as 67.2cm^2 is 100% unreasonable so I would like some of you guys to have a go, I took an assumption maybe its not possible to automate with desmos, either way, I think I may have to do it with working out so if that is possible that would be great. good luck to you all if you attempt this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is going on. I checked the parameters of the polynomial regression and they are correct.

Now, what I have is
$$\int_0^{8.5}f(x)\,dx=26.8718$$

Using an interpolating function (needing to extrapolate it between $x=0$ and $x=0.5$), I obtain
$$\int_0^{8.5}f(x)\,dx=\frac{6403}{240}=26.6792$$

Comment: Do you mind sharing your working out? for the first one? also for the 26.6792, is this a more accurate method of obtaining area under a curve?

Comment: @BAZAMEEE. First I would like to understand what did happen wth your graphing tool. Try others; there are plenty od on line calculators for interpolating methods (they are better than polynomial fits) and there are dozens of methods for that. Let me know. Cheers :-)

Comment: That was just desmos and to be fair that wasn't polynomial regression rather 6th regression but I took it as the same thing as they typically worked the same in the past and have similar traits for calculus. I don't think my teacher would like me to go out and do a method that we haven't touched or is not in the exam, so far we have focused on integrals and the trapezium method. but for what I know integrals are the more accurate methods as it gives an exact value.

Comment: Hey do you mind if i could contact you personally for this question? i am very curious how you done this

Comment: @BAZAMEEE. My e-mail address is in my profile. Go on !